# How can I set a folder for After Effects to watch for JSON/text files?

Tags: javascript, json, adobe, extendscript, after-effects

I'm successfully using the following extend-script (with [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js)) to read a local JSON file, and change a text layer in my project. How could I modify this script so that, when ran, it continuously 'watches' for new JSON files that are added to the directory, and runs the rest of the script?

```
#include "json2.js" // jshint ignore:line
var script_file = File($.fileName); // get the location of the script file
var script_file_path = script_file.path; // get the path

var file_to_read = File(script_file_path + "/unique-job-id.json");
var my_JSON_object = null; // create an empty variable
var content; // this will hold the String content from the file
  if(file_to_read !== false){// if it is really there
    file_to_read.open('r'); // open it
    content = file_to_read.read(); // read it
    my_JSON_object =  JSON.parse(content);// now evaluate the string from the file
    //alert(my_JSON_object.arr[1]); // if it all went fine we have now a JSON Object instead of a string call length
    var theComposition = app.project.item(1);
    var theTextLayer = theComposition.layers[1];
    theTextLayer.property("Source Text").setValue(my_JSON_object.arr[2]);
    file_to_read.close(); // always close files after reading
    }else{
    alert("Error reading JSON"); // if something went wrong
  }
```

Comment: I think it is not possible to have a script run permanently in the background. The script blocks the current running UI thread. You could take a look into plugin development for After Effects. [adobe.com/devnet/aftereffects](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/aftereffects.html)

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Object Model:
**Application scheduleTask()** method
  *app.scheduleTask(stringToE xecute, delay, repeat)*
  Description:
  *Schedules the specified JavaScript for delayed execution.*

So app.scheduleTask(string,delay,true) is exactly what you are looking for.Like this:

```
app.schduleTask('taskToWatchFile()',1000,true);

function taskToWatchFile(){
/*
 *Add your code here
 */
}
```